# Perl using hash during declaration

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I'd like to have all the items in `cflags` automatically in `cppflags`. How do I? Following fail code:

```
my %conf = (
    'cflags'   => ['-g', '-O0'],
    'cppflags' => [ @{$conf{cflags}} ],
    'bindir'   => $PWD . "/bin",
);
```

Sorry for the silly question, I'm new to perl :P.

Comment: Copy paste the flags from cflags to cppflags? Or add an assignment afterwards such as `$conf{cppflags} = $conf{cflags}`.

Comment: @TLP copypasting is dirty. The second way is fine, but does there exist any nicer way, in-line ?

Comment: This variable initialization. Its not dynamic, so how can it matter how you make the assignment? You cannot use the keys in `%conf` before they are created, so it must be done either with the same data or afterwards: It can't be done "in-line".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're still building the list to assign to `%conf`, so nothing's been assigned to `%conf` yet, so trying to read from `$conf{cflags}` is going to be fruitless.

Option 1:

```
my @cflags = qw( -g -O0 );
my %conf = (
    cflags   => [ @cflags ],
    cppflags => [ @cflags ],
    bindir   => "$PWD/bin",
);
```

Option 2:

```
my %conf;
$conf{cflags  } = [qw( -g -O0 )];
$conf{cppflags} = [ @{ $conf{cflags} } ];
$conf{bindir  } = "$PWD/bin";
```

Option 3:

```
my %conf = (
    cflags => [qw( -g -O0 )],
    bindir => "$PWD/bin",
);
$conf{cppflags} = [ @{ $conf{cflags} } ];
```

(In decreasing order of personal preference.)

Comment: I'd upvote you twice if I could. Sadly I can't even upvote you once (less than 15 rep), so have a motivational comment instead :D.

Comment: (In fact, `my $conf` hasn't even been executed yet! The assignment operator evaluates it's RHS before its LHS. This allows stuff like `my $x = 3; { my $x = $x; ++$x; say $x; #4 } say $x; #3`.)

Comment: re option 1: any reason not to do `cflags => \@cflags, cppflags => \@cflags, ...`?

Comment: @JoelBerger: That would work, but because both hash values reference the same array any modification to one would also change the other.

Comment: @Joel Berger, 1. That's not the same, and that's not what the OP did. 2. There's no indication that the OP wanted to do link those two. (By the way, the same question could be asked of option 2 and 3 for `$conf{cflags}` vs `[ @{ $conf{cflags} } ]`. Same answer.)

Comment: `all the items in cflags automatically in cppflags`, I could read that as, "any change to cflags should be reflected in cppflags".

Comment: @Joel Berger, Then why did he go out of his way to create a copy? Again, you're telling me to change an aspect of the OP's code he didn't ask to change.

Comment: I'm not saying you need to change anything, I'm saying he's new to Perl (as per the question) and maybe he didn't know you can take a direct reference and use it like that. Tell you what, I'll just answer in another answer, its a rather different perspective anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on ikegami's answer, here is one other suggestion that has a slightly different use case:

```
my @cflags = qw( -g -O0 );
my %conf = (
    cflags   => \@cflags,
    cppflags => \@cflags,
    bindir   => "$PWD/bin",
);
```

This is different that his #1 because the `@cflags` array and the values of the keys `cflags` and `cppflags` are all related to the same array. Change any one of them and the others will reflect the change. Perhaps this is the behavior what you want, or perhaps its not, or maybe it makes no difference to you, but there it is.